# What would be the best way to dynamically add a set of rows to a table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a following table using MVC that shows number of items the user has.

```
 <table border = "1" id="tblItems">
            <%
                var itemnum = 1;
                foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {%>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="Silver"><strong>Item#<%=itemnum%></strong></td>
                    <td><%=Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteItem", "Item", new { id = item.ID })%></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBox("ItemName_" + itemnum, item.Name)%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Description:</strong></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBox("ItemDescription_" + itemnum, item.Description)%></td>
                </tr>


                <%itemnum++;
           } %>
        </table>
```

I will have a button that will Add New Item that will dynamically add identical structure.

Also, How would I assign a unique ID to each of the input controls? 
In my controller I need to loop through total number of items and get a value from each input control by Request.Form.Get("Name_" + i);

Any ideas on what is the best way to do this using JQuery?

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to duplicate the last row:

```
$("#tblItems tr:last").clone().appendTo("#tblItems");
```

But that will carry over your `inputs` with the same names as the last row, not a great out-of-the-box solution. You can add some [extensive jQuery manipulation](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/add-new-raw-in-table-and-rename-the-input-field-name) to re-name the inputs, or, as Dan Diplo pointed out, there are some jQuery extensions that can do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

user(then a big number) :)

take a look at jqote (a jquery templating library). very small and can do exactly as you mention above. in fact, here's a small example doing just what you're after:

http://hackingon.net/post/jQuery-client-side-templates-with-jqote-and-AspNet-MVC.aspx

good luck - i've used it with great success.

jim

Comment: How would I assign a unique ID to each of the input controls? In my controller I need to loop through total number of items and get a value from each input control by Request.Form.Get("Name_" + i);

Comment: user,

inside the jqote template, there are two 'variables' that are present system wide names i and j. variable i is related to any collection that is being looped over and variable j is related to the tempalte invocation. 

these are persistant per page request (i.e. automatically get incremented in the backgound until the page is navigated away from). so you could have an id along the lnes of id="cliemtRow"<%i%> etc. you can gt the detail on this from here:

http://aefxx.com/api/jqote2-reference/#$jqote

Comment: ...cont due to comment length...


the author of the plugin is very helpful and will prolly give you a full blown example of what your after if you direct your question his way.

good luck

jim

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in raw jQuery using the .clone() method, but as Chris Pebble points out it doesn't rename your element names and Ids. However, there are a couple of jQuery plug-ins that help make this easy, so check out:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dupeIt

> "dupeIt is a jquery plugin that allows
>   you to duplicate and remove DOM
>   elements and their children with one
>   click. dupeIt smartly renames
>   duplicated elements by appending the
>   iteration number, ex.
>   "txt_mytextfield" duplicate would be
>   "txt_mytextfield2".

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clonefield

> "jQuery.cloneField is a plugin that
>   provides you with easy, dynamic form
>   field (or any other DOM element,
>   really) duplication and removal."

Comment: Looks like Dupeit's homepage is down.
I agree that clone will not work in my case.
What do you think of Append() or AppendTo() functions?

Thanks!